# jQuery UI auto-complete response index problem

Tags: jquery, response

I am using the jQuery ui-complete library which calls an endpoint via get request to populate a list of suggested autors:

```
$("#author-name").autocomplete({
                source: "/authors/get.json",
                minLength: 5,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $("#author-name").val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#author-id").val(ui.item.value);
                }

});
```

The issue is the format of the reply, which is wrapped inside an indexed array as follows:

```
{
    "reply": [
        {
            "value": 9,
            "label": "Joe Bloggs"
        },
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to tell the response to be treated from the reply object, something like:

```
select: function(event, ui.reply) {
```

I've read the api docs on the library but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is expecting an array so you are going to have to adjust what you are assigning to it.
 In the example below, I simply made a new function to get the data then access the `reply` array and that is what I pass to Autocomplete `source`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getResponse() {
    var response = {
      "reply": [{
          "value": 9,
          "label": "Joe Bloggs"
        },
        {
          "value": 10,
          "label": "foo"
        },
      ]
    }; // in your case: read data from /authors/get.json

    return response.reply;
  }

  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: getResponse(),
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(ui.item.value);
      console.log(ui.item.label);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ECMAScript 6, you can make use of object destructuring:

```
select: function(event, { reply }) {
```

`reply` now will be what otherwise you'd access with `ui.reply`.

Comment: This doesn't work, I've realised that the select function is related to what happens once you have selected an item. I can't get any of the suggestions to appear in the first place

Comment: You asked how to automatically retrieve 'reply' out of the second argument of the function - so you got these answers. If you have another question, either fix yours or ask a new one. I'm not sure I understand your problem currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it this way

```
select: function(event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var reply = ui.reply;
//And Because it is an array you should use index on it.
                $("#author-name").val(reply[0].label);
                $("#author-id").val(reply[0].value);
            }
```

Comment: This similarly doesn't work - see my first comment above